# using axios with firebase , do i have to install firebase from npm?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

I have setup axios in my project like so,

In my `src/` folder created a axios.js file that looks like so:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL : 'https://myprojectname-11651.firebaseio.com/'
});

export default instance;
```

Then in my main component where i use axios i use it like so:

```
import axios from '../axios.js';

// removing code thats not necessary for this example

componentDidMount() {
        // alert();

        axios.get('/habits/badHabits.json')
            .then( (resp) => {
                console.log(resp);
            })

    }
```

I get a 401 error in my console, The dashboard for firebase seems to have changed from a year back and i am not unable to use axios with firebase like i used it over a year ago.

My database look like so:

[image]

How exactly do i use axios with firebase ? do i have to install firebase from npm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling you are mixing up the Real Time Database REST API and the Firestore one.

From the picture in your question, you are using Firestore.

And for Firestore, "all REST API endpoints exist under the base URL https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/", see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls).

On the other hand, as detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data), the Real Time DB REST API endpoints have a base URL like https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/.... which is similar to the URL in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to install firebase in your project using npm. It is initial process to configure your app with firebase. Then you have to add firebase credentials like

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: <YOUR_APP_KEY>,
    authDomain: "<YOUR_APP_DOMAIN>",
    databaseURL: "<YOUR_DATABASE_URL>",
    projectId: "<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<YOUR_STORAGE_URL>",
    messagingSenderId: "<YOUR_MESSENGER_ID>"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

**Instruction:- You can find the above code here,
Firebase console > Project Settings (This is the gear icon opposite of "Project overview" text) > Your apps > (On same page you will have three choices to either use it for android, ios , web) > Add Firebase to your web app**

Now that you have added these things you just need to use firebase functions to access the firebase storage, authentication, database.

Here is the link where you can find all your details
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

It will help you.